# Angle between vectors $a-b$ and $-j-k$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given vectors $a and b$ and asked to "measure the angle between $a - b$ and $-j - k$".

How do I obtain $-j-k$?

Comment: $j = (0,1,0)$ and $k = (0,0,1)$.

Comment: Is this  solely  because of the given -j-k or is there another reason?

Comment: The convention for axes is often written:  $\hat{i} = (1,0,0)$, $\hat{j} = (0,1,0)$, and $\hat{k} = (0,0,1)$.  What do *you* call the coordinate vectors??

Comment: I call it the same, I just wanted to know why its 1 in each coordinate for each vector but it seems to be trivial.

Comment: Normalization...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a = (3,4,-2)$  and $b=(-0,2,1)$ $\Rightarrow$ $a-b=(3,2,-3)$

$\cos\theta=\dfrac{\langle(a-b)(-j-k)\rangle}{ \|a-b||\|-j-k\|}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\theta=\arccos\biggl(\dfrac{\langle(a-b)(-j-k)\rangle}{\|a-b\|\|-j-k\|}\biggr)$

$\cos\theta=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{11}}$ which implies $\theta=\arccos\dfrac{\sqrt{11}}{22}$

Comment: Not an answer to the question asked

Comment: What did you use for -j-k?

Comment: i used standart basis vectors.j=(0,1,0) and k=(0,0,1)

Comment: ok perfect! Thats what I wanted to know. Thank you!